# Stripping out the limit in this php code

Tags: php, wordpress

I found this code for displaying wordpress posts on my page from an RSS feed. However it has a limit to display only 5 posts.

```
<?php
    $rss = new DOMDocument();
    $rss->load('http://wordpress.org/news/feed/');
    $feed = array();
    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
        $item = array ( 
            'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            );
        array_push($feed, $item);
    }
    $limit = 5;
    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
        $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
        $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
        $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
        $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
        echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
        echo '<small><em>Posted on '.$date.'</em></small></p>';
        echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
    }
?>
```

I could just increase the $limit to "50" for example but if I have less that 50 posts it will show me an error.

My guess would be to strip out these lines but it seems to stop the script functioning:

```
$limit = 5;
for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do. You basically limit it to all the items contained in the feed.

```
$limit = count($feed);
```

I would also wrap it in an `if` to ensure it has items.

```
$limit = count($feed);
if ($limit > 0)
{
    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
        $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
        $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
        $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
        $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
        echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
        echo '<small><em>Posted on '.$date.'</em></small></p>';
        echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Whilst

```
$limit = count($feed);
```

Would work, it could also lead to a huge number of articles being displayed.

You could try

```
$count = count($feed);
$limit = $count > 50 ? 50 : $count;
```

This would limit it to 50 if there were more than that

Answer (score 1):

Use **`limit`** as the number of **`feed`** comes

```
$limit = count($feed);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`count()`](http://php.net/count) to count the number of elements in an array as follows:

```
$limit = count($feed); //store number of elements

if ($limit > 0) { //checking if at least one element exists

    for($x=0; $x<$limit ;$x++) { 
    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
    $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
    $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
    echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
    echo '<small><em>Posted on '.$date.'</em></small></p>';
    echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
    }

}
```

Hope this helps!